# Show no internet connection dialog with Retrofit and OkHttp

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I know there are a lot of examples for this question, but couldn't find any better solution (except of [this](https://medium.com/@tsaha.cse/advanced-retrofit2-part-1-network-error-handling-response-caching-77483cf68620), but not working on kotlin). In most examples if there's no internet connection goes to exception and crashs app.

So, Is it possible to show Dialog/Toast with no internet error?

Comment: you can have a connection but no internet so you can try to connect to a web socket and check for internet 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27312494/8528047

Comment: Yes, you can override the `onInternetUnavailable()` in the activity and display Dialog/Toast.

Comment: your approach is correct, can you provide your LogCat when crash occurs ?

Comment: there is no such thing that works in java and doesn't work in kotlin, you are making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I'm using MVVM pattern and when I call onInternetUnavailable() in my Activity, mInternetConnectionListener is always null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)